# How To Change Appearance Of Sheets In Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

After updating my computer, I have found a very ugly change to the layout of excel.

Does anyone know how to change the appearance from this monstrosity back to something more normal?

Sheet:
[image]

Looking for sharp edges, smaller tab size, and to have the selected sheet's tab "stand out" more

Comment: Have you selected a different Office theme?

Comment: Yes, but the themes just change the color, not the tabs for the different work sheets

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-new-look-of-office-a6cdf19a-b2bd-4be1-9515-d74a37aa59bf) of Microsoft the changes were enrolled with the newest updates, but can be changed individually for the office applications. To change the theme select "File" > "Account". In this menu change the "Office theme" on another theme that isn't named "Use system settings".
[image: How to change the office theme]

Comment: Thanks, but that just changes the background colors